# AS3 - Autosize button label text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, text, label

Is there a way in flash professional Actionscript3 to set button label with autosize?
I have many button on stage with different size and different label text on one line.
I want to auto-adapt size of entire label text inside my (all) button.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this :

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    
    public class CreateButton extends MovieClip
    {
        public var btnBG: MovieClip;
        public var btn_text: TextField;

        public function CreateButton( btnName :String ) 
        {
            btn_text = new TextField();
            btn_text.text = ( btnName ) ? btnName : '';
            btn_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            
            btnBG.width = btn_text.width;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. but how can apply this code at my button already on stage with instance name MyButton and with label text already filled?

Comment: And I want to resize label text not the width button